# Issues with sscanf in C

Tags: c, csv, parsing, scanf

I am writing a program that could read a text with csv format and I am having this issue where the sscanf only parses the whole thing as one string when it is separated by ','.

For example, a code snippet below

```
char str[100] = "Alex,2933,89,";
char name[50] = "";
int id;
double mark;

sscanf(str, "%s,%d,%lf,", name, &id, &mark);
printf("%s\n", name);
printf("%d\n", id);
printf("%f\n", mark);
```

Output was:

```
Alex,2933,89,
896
0.000000
```

Which is clearly not the expected output.
But when str is edited to `str = "Alex 2933 89 "`, the code is giving me the correct output.

The working code:

```
char str[100] = "Alex 2933 89 ";
char name[50] = "";
int id;
double mark;

sscanf(str, "%s %d %lf ", name, &id, &mark);
printf("%s\n", name);
printf("%d\n", id);
printf("%f\n", mark);
```

Correct Output:

```
Alex
2933
89.000000
```

Can I know how do I fix this?

Comment: Can you correct the correct output?

Comment: Hint:  Always check for the return value of function calls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`%s` stops at white space, the fact that you put a `,` in the format string does not change this behavior. You should use the `%[^,]` conversion specification.

Change the code this way:

```c
char str[100] = "Alex,2933,89,";
char name[50] = "";
int id;
double mark;

if (sscanf(str, "%49[^,],%d,%lf,", name, &id, &mark) == 3) {
    printf("%s\n", name);
    printf("%d\n", id);
    printf("%f\n", mark);
}
```

Note however that `%[^,]` cannot parse empty fields. If the CSV line may contain empty fields, such as `,23,89.0,` `sscanf()` will fail to convert `name` because no character matches the `%[^,]` specification. If you have such lines in the source file, you should parse the string fields manually with `strchr()` or `strcspn()`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and it works. But can I ask what do you mean by " .... %[^,] cannot parse empty fields." ? Sorry I am still new to C